# Copy data from one cell to another if condition met VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck at this rather elementary problem, in spite of trying to get it solved thru a google search. I need to copy the data from CELL C to CELL A if the condition within InStr argument is met. The condition is that the cell in column C beings with the letter V.

Sample Table: Excel

```
 - Component(A) Description(B) Duplicate(C)
 - V806700.B01  Part 1         V806700.B12
 - V806700.B02  Part 2         V806700.B13
 - V806700.B03  Part 3         NA
 - V806700.B04  Part 4         NA
 - V806700.B05  Part 5         V806700.B55
 - V806700.B06  Part 6         NA
```

Code:

``````
`````
Sub copythecell()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("C2:C7")
    If InStr(cell.Value, "V") > 0 Then
        cell.Offset(0, -2).Copy
        ActiveCell.Paste
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
``````

Comment: `If InStr(cell.Value, "V") > 0` would copy cells with `V` anywhere in it, not just as the first letter btw. And you're looping over the cells in column A, not column C.

Comment: BigBen, i made the edit, that was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub copythecell()
    
    Dim cell As Range, v
    
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A7").Cells
        v = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        If v Like "V*" Then cell.Value = v
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but its it ok to use a wildcard search?

Comment: It's not a full wildcard  - it's "begins with V" - if you wanted to be more restrictive you could do something like "V#*" (begins with V followed by a digit)